# Clicking a button generated by Javascript with Selenium

Tags: javascript, flash, button, selenium

I'd like to use `Selenium` or other package to automatically click the "**Copy**" button on one web page.
 It seems that the button is generated by `Javascript`. Is it possible to do so? Thanks in advance!

`<script src="media/portal/js/table-maker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Here is the piece of code in `table-maker.js` related to the "Copy" button:

```
    this.generateEntityTable = function(entityName, ajaxDataProperty, 
        urlSuffix, objectHeadings, objectFields, hiddenFields, 
        tableSelector, tableId, 
        emptyMessage) {
    if (!emptyMessage) {
        emptyMessage = "No data available in table";
    }
    var oTable = $(tableSelector);
    var tableElt = oTable[0];
    var tableSource = {
            "sourceType" : "json",
            "structure" : {
                "headings" : objectHeadings,
                "fields" : objectFields
            }
    }; 
    TableUtils.buildTableHtml(tableElt, tableSource.structure.headings);
    var tableToolsProps = null;

    if ('portalFile' == entityName) { // table does not allow row selection. 
        tableToolsProps = { 
            "aButtons" : []
        };
    } else if ('bspsample' == entityName) {
        tableToolsProps = {
            "aButtons"  : [{
                "sExtends": "copy",
                "mColumns": "all"
            },
            {   
                "sExtends": "csv",
                "mColumns": "all"
            },
            {
                "sExtends": "xls",
                "mColumns": "all"
            }],
            "sSwfPath"  : "media/table-tools-2.1.5/media/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"
        };
    } else {
        tableToolsProps = {
            "sRowSelect": "single",
            "aButtons"  : []
        };
    }

    // this is to prevent DataTables from putting warnings or errors in an alert box.
    $.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
    try {
        oTable.dataTable({
            "bDestroy" : true,
            "bRetrieve" : true,
            "bJQueryUI" : true,
            "bProcessing" : true,
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "sAjaxSource" : initialUrl + "rest/"+ urlSuffix,
            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                $.ajax( {
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "success": function(result){fnCallback(result);},
                    "failure":function(result){alert('failure');}
                } );
            },
            "sAjaxDataProp" : ajaxDataProperty,
            "aoColumns" : this.fieldsToColumnProperties(objectFields, objectHeadings, 
                hiddenFields, entityName, tableSelector, tableId),
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": tableToolsProps,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sEmptyTable": "Please wait - Fetching records"
              },

              fnInitComplete: function(oSettings){
                  oSettings.oLanguage.sEmptyTable = emptyMessage;
                  $(oTable).find(".dataTables_empty").html(emptyMessage);
               }
        }); 
    } catch (err) {
        var messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
        messageHandler.showError("Internal client error: " + err + " Unable to create table for entity: " 
            + entityName);
    };

    // this is required for row_selected styles to work.
    oTable.addClass('display');
    oTable.show(); // in case it was hidden
    return oTable;
};
```

Comment: Those buttons are created in Flash. You will not be able to click on them in pure Selenium, you will need another tool to click on them. Something like AutoIt, Genie, Sikuli, Robot.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying `Sikuli`. Do you have an example code to do so?

Comment: Personally I have only used Genie and AutoIt.

Comment: Thanks! It is still helpful to provide an example code of Genie or AutoIt.

Comment: How about driver.findElement(By.cssSelecor("a.DTTT_button_copy")).click() with proper waiting and sync?

Comment: I have an example of 4 different ways of launching AutoIt here: https://sourceforge.net/p/sebase/code/HEAD/tree/sebase-groovy/src/test/groovy/net/sourceforge/sebase/demos/AutoItTest.groovy

Comment: I have some small examples of launching Genie here: https://sourceforge.net/p/genieos/code-0/HEAD/tree/trunk/demos/